# File Not Found error while adding relative URL to Navigation Link

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation

I have a publishing site migrated from SharePoint 2007 to 2010. I am trying to add relative URL under Navigation.

My URL looks like this '`/Sites/SiteColl2/Pages/Default.aspx`'. The URL I am trying to add is of different site collection. After adding this URL when I click 'OK' on 'AreaNavigationSettings.aspx' page I get 'File Not Found.' error.

If I add absolute URL like '`http://domainname.com//Sites/SiteColl2/Pages/Default.aspx`' it works perfectly fine. But requirement is to add relative URL.

Please suggest me if you have any solution.

Appreciate your inputs.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want relative url from the same site collection or from different site collection? different site colelction is from different web app or same?

Comment: relative URL is from different site collection under different web app.